Is there a way to create a batch file that will make folders with sub-folders with even more sub folders quickly and without specifying the path?
I'm currently trying to write a batch file to create folders and sub-folders and well even more sub-folders in those sub-folders.
Currently I've been able to make main folders and a single set of sub-folders with this
md 1 2 3 4 5 & FOR /D %G in ("*") DO cd "%CD%\%`nxG" & md 1 2 3 4 5

but this only works in a cmd window and only makes a single subset of sub-folders, is there a way I can extend this to make another set of folders within the sub-folders? And how would I convert this to work in a .bat file.
First post so sorry if I'm not clear or I have incorrect tags.
Full explanation for how this works
md 1 2 3 4 5 & FOR /D %G in ("*") DO cd "%CD%\%`nxG" & md 1 2 3 4 5

as I'm not entirely sure and explanations for replies would be very much appreciated for anyone else who stumbles across this looking for answers.

It doesn't work because %\nxGis wrong. It should be%~nxG. For a batch file you'd use %%G inand%%~nxG`.

Thank you for the reply and explanation, do you know if possible how you would continue to make a 3rd set of sub folders like folder1 - subfolder1 - subsubfolder 1?

I understand my apologies, the help was very much appreciated.

You could try something with three For or For /L loops. Open a Command Prompt window, type For /? and press the [ENTER] key to see how you might be able to do that.

Thanks again for the reply I will continue to mess around and see if I can solve my problem.

Example using For: @For %%G In (1 2 3 4 5) Do @For %%H In (1 2 3 4 5) Do @For %%I In (1 2 3 4 5) Do @MD "Sub-Dir %%G\Sub-Sub-Dir %%H\Sub-Sub-Sub-Dir %%I". Example using For /L: @For /L %%G In (1 1 5) Do @For /L %%H In (1 1 5) Do @For /L %%I In (1 1 5) Do @MD "Sub-Dir %%G\Sub-Sub-Dir %%H\Sub-Sub-Sub-Dir %%I".

Here is a simple one line code, using PoweShell
powershell.exe cd 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents';$FolderNames=1..5;(mkdir $FolderNames).ForEach{cd $_.FullName;(mkdir $FolderNames)}.ForEach{cd $_.FullName;(mkdir $FolderNames)}.ForEach{cd $_.FullName;(mkdir $FolderNames)}


This question was originally tagged with a 'PowerShell' tag, so I created a PowerShell script, embedded within a batch file.
' 2> nul
:: Your begging bat code here
powershell -Command "Invoke-Expression (Get-Content -Path %~f0 -Raw)"
:: Continue your bat code


:: End of bat code
exit
' | Out-Null
# Start of PowerShell code


Set-Location -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Documents"
$folders = 1..10 | foreach { New-Item -Name $_ -ItemType Directory }

foreach ($folder in $folders) {

    Set-Location $folder.FullName
    $Subfolders = 1..10 | foreach { New-Item -Name $_ -ItemType Directory }

    foreach ($Subfolder in $Subfolders) {

        Set-Location $Subfolder.FullName
        1..10 | foreach { New-Item -Name $_ -ItemType Directory }

    }

}


@Compo look my edit

It appears to still be using the PowerShell language! Also ' 2> nul is not a valid batch file command, and both lines beginning with :: are supposed to use Rem instead. The PowerShell tag was correctly removed from the initial question, because there was no mention of it in the body text, or title, and the submitted code was only batch/cmd.exe internal commands. This site helps to fix code, not provide code in any tagged language irrespective of the OP's own code submission.

It would probably be more robust to use '%~f0' over %~f0, and possibly safer to use -LiteralPath rather than -Path too. Also, if you notice my commented examples under the main question, you might consider a method which does not unnecessarily change the current directory throughout the script.

the correct way to embed powershell in a batch script would look like this: https://pastebin.com/a4jieQ7X
